# How does a Successive Aproximation ADC Handle Negative Voltages?

Tags: adc, encoder

First, apologies for what must seem a simple question to most of you. I do understand the SAR algorithm. And Two's complement representation. My question is algorithmic. When a negative voltage is presented to a bipolar SAR ADC, is the "sign" stripped and MSB set to 1, then the normal SAR algorithm applied, then is the resultant bit code converted to Two's Complement?  Or is the algorithm generating Two's Complement code directly? How?

Comment: Do you mean "negative voltage" rather than negative value?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Negative input voltages

Comment: I believe I am asking a "fundamental" question.  I have searched the web and found examples of how a positive voltage is converted to a digital value (SAR).  But I have not seen how this is done with a negative voltage.

Comment: Do you have an example of a device where you think this might be being done?

Comment: The actual chip is an AD7656.  I am trying to write a small model that will allow me understand the conversion process.  I can convert postive voltages.  And I can convert negative voltages if I strip the sign and use the same algorithm (use sign to set MSB).  But my understanding is that the output of this device is Two's Complement. So I am wondering if the Two's Complement representation is done after the conversion, but inside the device.  Again, appologies.  I'm out of my depth on this one.

Answer (score 2):

The only real requirement for proper operation is that the DAC in the SAR be monotonic.  So you can have a 2's complement arithmetic path as long as you have a 2's complement DAC.  That means that your binary search also has to be able to handle 2's complement.

Conversely, if you have your DAC span from 0x0000 = -15 V, 0x7FFF = 0V & 0xFFFF = 15 V your counting and search math/control is much simpler.  You then need to do the conversion on the output value.

Another consideration is that the DAC may be simply a binary weighted charge redistribution structure which is inherently fast , low power,accurate and small.  These are easiest to design on a span from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF like the second scenario.

In short, it's hard to know as there are many alternatives available.  But my bets would be on the third scenario.